# Update text on screen using switch cases based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a screen with four drop downs. Each drop down has options. Based on the selection, I want a text 'description' to show up on the screen.

Drop down / options :

- Carbs -> Rice (RI) (default selected) / Bread (BR)
- Protein -> Chicken (C) (default selected)
- Fat -> (None) / Butter (BT) / Olive Oil (OI)
- Fruit -> (None) / Apple (AP) / Orange (OR)

Currently, all of my options have a 'code' from a table which is being displayed correctly but is not very descriptive. For example, if I pick Rice, Chicken, None and Apple, my screen displays:

- Carbs: RI
- Protein: C
- Fat:
- Fruit: AP

I want to show the description based on what the selected option is:

- Carbs: RI - Rice
- Protein: C - Chicken
- Fat:
- Fruit: AP - Apple

The relevant code I have working to show the selected option (without description based on selected option) is:

```
<script>
    function initializeForm() {}
</script>

<body class="Outside" style="background-color:black;" onload="initializeForm();" onkeyup="forminput(event);">
    <center>

        <table class="Inside" style="height:435px; width:535px;">
            <tr class="mainTop">
                <th style="height:22px;">Food&nbsp;Menu&nbspOptions</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <span style="clear:both;color:darkred; font-weight:bold;">Please Confirm Your Selected Options:<br />&nbsp;<br /></span>

                    <div style="float:left; width:28%; text-align:right;">Carbs:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:24%; text-align:left; border-bottom:1px solid black;">&nbsp;(option1)</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:3%;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:13%; text-align:right;">Protein:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:24%; text-align:left; border-bottom:1px solid black;">&nbsp;(option2)</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:3%;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:28%; text-align:right;">Fat:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:24%; text-align:left; border-bottom:1px solid black;">&nbsp;(option3)</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:3%;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:13%; text-align:right;">Fruit:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:24%; text-align:left; border-bottom:1px solid black;">&nbsp;(option4)</div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:3%;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mainBottom">
                <th style="height:20px;">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

I want to learn how to be able to do this using switch statements in a function (in the initializeForm function?) and div IDs/getelementbyID for the individual drop downs.

I'm a beginner to JS/HTML so I apologize for any confusion. Just trying to figure this out - thank you!

Comment: Why not use the `select` object provided by HTML and then use Javascript to add the values like you're currently doing?  What you've currently got is rather an "interesting" solution using divs.  You could then use the `onchange` function on the `<select`> object to update the description: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: I second this, I dont see a <form> tag or a <select> tag. Interesting solution, but using those elements add much better functionality and support... Don't get stuck using bad habits just because you created them! good luck

Comment: I am new on the project and this is how the existing code has been set up - I am currently modifying and learning as I work on it. If I did want to implement a solution using div ids and switch statement, would I assign a div id to the existing divs, and then write a function with switch cases and 'getelementbyid'?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with a `<div>`, you can do something like this. However, the code below only implemented a small portion of the functionalities of a `<select>` tag with a lot of code. Also, using a `<div>` to implement a form like your is not a good practice as it hinders accessibility. You can just do it with a simple `<select>`

```js
var inputDataFromUser = {
    protein: '',
};

function toggleDropdown() {
    var optionsDiv = this.querySelector('.option-mock');

    optionsDiv.classList.contains('hidden')
        ? optionsDiv.classList.remove('hidden')
        : optionsDiv.classList.add('hidden');
}

function closeDropdown() {
    var optionsDiv = this.querySelector('.option-mock');

    optionsDiv.classList.add('hidden');
}

function selectValue(name) {
    var value = this.textContent;
    var displayValueContainer = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.children[0];

    displayValueContainer.textContent = value;
    inputDataFromUser[name] = value;
}

function logValueFromSelect() {
    var select = document.querySelector('select');

    console.log(select.value);
}
```

```css
.select-mock {
    position: relative;
}

.select-mock > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
    width: 100%;
}

.select-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.option-mock > div {
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: white;
}

.option-mock > div:hover {
    color: white;
    background: cornflowerblue;
}

.no-user-select {
    user-select: none;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <table class="Inside" style="height:100px; width:535px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <div style="float:left; width:13%; text-align:right;">Protein:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                <div
                    style="float:left; width:24%; text-align:left; border-bottom:1px solid black;"
                    class="select-mock no-user-select"
                    tabindex="0"
                    onclick="toggleDropdown.call(this)"
                    onblur="closeDropdown.call(this)"
                >
                    <div>
                        <span>&nbsp;(option2)</span>
                        <span class="select-triangle">&#9662;</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option-mock hidden">
                        <div onclick="selectValue.call(this, 'protein')">None</div>
                        <div onclick="selectValue.call(this, 'protein')">BT - Butter</div>
                        <div onclick="selectValue.call(this, 'protein')">OI - Olive Oil</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Or you could just do it like this, much simpler -->
                <select>
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    <option value="BT - Butter">BT - Butter</option>
                    <option value="OI - Olive Oil">OI - Olive Oil</option>
                </select>
                <!-- Or you could just do it like this, much simpler -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button onclick="console.log(inputDataFromUser)">Click (value from div)</button>
    <button onclick="logValueFromSelect()">Click (value from select)</button>
</center>
```